# How can I specify fmt parameter 'width' for mailx command?

Tags: unix, sendmail, mailx

I am using the command

```
cat ~/2014-02-06_BP.txt | mailx -s "formatted file content" myemail@mydomain.com
```

I believe mailx uses `fmt` internally. I want to change the fmt width parameters to `fmt -s -w160`.

ps: This is on Fedora 20

Comment: Have you actually looked at the source for mailx and found `fmt` in it or is this a guess you've made based on how the message looks when you read it on the other end? I'd guess it's the reader that's doing the reformatting.

Comment: I have not looked at the source. My question is probably better framed as mailx appears to be cutting width down to a number. I want it to be 160.

Comment: I really doubt that mailx is doing that. I see you have a sendmail tag on the question also. How do you know it's mailx and not sendmail or something else? You should at least specify whose mailx you're using since the different unix vendors don't use exactly the same code.

Answer (score 0):

mailx is almost certainly NOT doing any formatting of intput cat-ed into it.

Your best bet would be to run fmt on the input before sending to mailx, eg:

```
  fmt -w 160 file.txt | mailx -s 'your data, formatted' somebody@someplace
```